# Get order information using Woocommerce api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I searched internet a lot to know how to use woocommerce api to get the order details using customers phone number or email or first and last etc.

I have not observed any where any sample code to get the complete order details with the customer number or email address or first name and last name. Any one please guide me a way to get this thing done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327341/get-all-customer-orders-in-woocommerce-api

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention in our website there is no account for customer all are guest checkouts! how can I handle the searches now?